# C++: Curly Braces Initialization Despite Explicit Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, initializer-list

I've had a data class (so like a struct in the C sense: a class with only a bunch of properties) that I used to initialize (through an implicit copy constructor, I think) with curly braces initializer lists, like so:

```
ClassName inst = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

I then decided I want to enable initialization from vectors, so I defined a ctor looking something like this:

```
ClassName(std::vector<int> vec) : A(vec[0]), B(vec[1]), C(vec[2]), D(vec[3]) {}
```

Ever since adding this constructor, though, the above-cited method of curly-braces-initialization no longer works due to "cannot conver from 'initializer list' to 'namespace::ClassName'".

I tried Googling for explanations/advice/solutions but couldn't find the right keywords and nothing I found seemed to answer my question exactly.

How would you advise getting around this (whether specifically how to re-enable such list initialization, or design-wise, if I should somehow avoid this scenario)?

Comment: Why would you enable initialization through a `std::vector` for an aggregate type with exactly four members? Maybe it would make sense to enable it for a `std::span` with static extent, but this is just conceptually wrong. If you really needed it, you could just make a free function that does it and keep using aggregate initialization.

Comment: @JanSchultke, my real use case involves the parsing of a vector created after a long pipeline, and I need to parse it into such an aggregate type. The aggregate type is always expected to be initialized out of a vector, and never in any other way (the initializer list is just a convenience sort of thing for when I'm testing it, and this question is mainly out of curiosity). Do I understand correctly that the conceptual issue you describe with using a vector is that a vector is dynamic in size, and that there are std containers better-suited for fixed-size situations?

Comment: Basically, though: the main thing is that I want a "named vector"; sort of like a dictionary, but with keys known in compile time, and used as part of an API. The contents of it are to be obtained after running a long pipeline that creates a vector, though I could in theory convert it from a vector to, say, an array, but there are several such classes in several different sizes, so I figured the simple way to "cover all cases" (so as to keep the actual pipeline as generic as possible) is to output a vector, and thus to consume a vector with the aggregates. Would appreciate your thoughts! :)

Comment: Yeah, the conceptual issue is that you're initializing a range with static extent to a range with dynamic extent. At the very least, this shouldn't belong in a constructor. Whatever function is responsible for obtaining the vector and then creating `ClassName`s from it should do this conversion from dynamic to static extent. You might also want to use `std::span`. You can explicitly convert from a span with dynamic extent to one with static extent, which is conceptually doing what you're doing, but you would keep the constructor clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this three classes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

struct aggregate {
    int a,b,c,d;
};
struct non_aggregate {
    int a,b,c,d;
    non_aggregate(std::vector<int>) {}
};
struct init_list_constr {
    int a,b,c,d;
    init_list_constr(std::initializer_list<int>) {}
};

int main() {
    aggregate a = {1,2,3,4};
    //non_aggregate b = {1,2,3,4}; // error
    init_list_constr c = {1,2,3,4};
}
```

`aggregate` is an aggregate because it has no user defined constructor. You can use aggregate initialization: `aggregate a = {1,2,3,4};`. `non_aggregate` is not an aggregate because it has a user defined constructor and you cannot use aggregate initialization.

I suggest you to provide a `std::initializer_list` constructor which makes aggregate initialization possible also with a user defined constructor.

For details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: @AnonA note that my code is just a toy example. The initializer lsit constructor just allows you to write `init_list_constr c = {1,2,3,4};` but you still need to write the code to initialize the members.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the user-defined constructor your class is no longer an [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (assuming it was before, because your question is incomplete), so the last rule of [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) applies:

> Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
> (...)
>
> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution **against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list**, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. (...).

So the compiler tries to pass 4 arguments of type `int` while your constructor expects 1 argument of type `std::vector<int>`. If you instead initialize your instance like this

```
ClassName inst = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

compiler will pick your 1-argument constructor that expects `std::vector<int>` and then convert `{1, 2, 3, 4}` to `std::vector<int>` using its [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking the `initializer_list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot – "aggregate initialization" was the keyword I was missing. Is there perhaps a way to enable such a default initializer-list constructor despite the existence of my explicit constructor, or do I have to take the nested-braces/vector initialization method you've suggested?

Comment: Yeah, you can add another ctor taking `initializer_list` and delegating to constructor taking vector: https://godbolt.org/z/cMj3rT67E - then the rule that I (...)-out will apply.

Comment: I marked @4463035818_is_not_an_ai's answer because it also happened to contain an answer to this question of mine, but yours was very helpful too – thank you very much for your time. Wish I could mark two answers!